# Android lost keystore , trying to recover using StellarPhoenicMacDataRecovery

Tags: android, keystore

So as it has happened with several android developers like me , they have lost their keystore for good and can no longer update their android application . I just wanted to give this a last try and thought to recover this using a disk recovery tool called as [StellarPhoenicMacDataRecovery](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21543/stellar-phoenix-mac-data-recovery) . Now , i tried to recover but with no success till it striked me that Stellar doesn't really know how the keystore looks like , so how can it search ? This made open settings to this page : [image: Add a custom file header using this] , so could someone tell me whats the header structure of the android keystore that I could try one last bet ?

Answer (score 1):

The keystores I've seen have started with the bytes

```
fe ed fe ed 00 00 00 02
```

You can inspect it yourself with

```
hexdump <keystore file> | head -1
```